# Interpreting an ERD

Tags: diagram, erd

What's the difference between the CategorySection-Category relationship and the CategorySection-Categorization relationship?

1. CategorySection-Category has an
   arrowhead and a black dot.
2. CategorySection-Categorization has
   an arrowhead on both ends.

Both are supposed to be "has many" relationships but this diagram uses a different symbol to represent these two relationships.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on tyhe notation you are using but typically:

- the crowsfoot (arrow) indicates many
- the black dot indicates required
- the white dot indicates optional

Note that just because a diagram is drawn doesn't makes the relationships it shows sensible, or even possible.

Comment: "Note that just because a diagram is drawn doesn't makes the relationships it shows sensible, or even possible." -> Do you mean that it's simply a visual representation but there's no verification of whether it makes good sense as a database schema?

Comment: The strange thing is that, now that I understand what the symbols mean, the generated diagram does not seem to reflect the underlying schema at all. Maybe there's something wrong with the tool.

Comment: If you extracted it from a database schema, it should normally reflect the schema. Of course, not all schemas make sense from a business perspective, indeed I suspect the majority do not.

Comment: "not all schemas make sense from a business perspective, indeed I suspect the majority do not" - you mean just because people have difficulty designing schemas effectively for business or because the emphasis in schema design is on technical considerations rather than business needs? Not sure I follow. Wouldn't it be quite a problem for a large number of businesses if what you said is true?

Comment: It IS a problem. Most business have enormous problems mapping their business processes onto database schema.

Answer (score 1):

Crowfeet on both ends indicate a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

- One Category can have many
  CategorySections, but one CategorySection can belong to one Category.
- One Categorization can have many Categories, but one Category can belong to only one Categorization.
- A Categorization can have many CategorySections and a CategorySection can belong to many Categorizations.

I think it tells someting like you can create many different categorizations that define different categories but categorysections can be shared among the different categories (and categorizations).